# How to get Image source path on onclick event of that Image clicked

Tags: javascript

I need to get the Image source when onclick event of the image is fired .

I tried using document.getElementById("example").src; , but the console on browser says

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeIt()
{
var name = document.getElementById("myimage").src;
alert(name);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img onclick="changeIt()" src='em1.gif' name='example' border='0' />
<img onclick="changeIt()" src='em2.gif' name='example' border='0' />
<img onclick="changeIt()" src='em3.gif' name='example' border='0' />
<img onclick="changeIt()" src='em4.gif' name='example' border='0' />
<img onclick="changeIt()" src='em5.gif' name='example' border='0' />
</body>
</html>
```

**Update part .**

The actual source is , on a AJAX Response , i will get Image Paths from a folder , for which i need to create Images dynamically and add them to a div .

This is actual code

```
outputdata.forEach(function (element) {
                   content = $("<div><a href='something'><img onclick='changeIt()' src='" + element + "'   /></a></div>");
                   content.addClass('content');
                   container.append(content);
                   $("#fp_thumbScroller").append(container);
                });
            }
```

so i didn't created ID , thinking as it is not suitable to have same id's for different images .

Comment: try `...onclick="changeIt(this.src)"...`

Comment: didn't you forget to add the ID attribute to img elements?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

html:

```
<img onclick="changeIt(this.src)" src='em1.gif' name='example' border='0' />
```

js:

```
function changeIt(_src){
    alert(_src);
}​
```

Comment: How to do it with a functional components?

Answer (score 7):

I would pass the actual element reference (this) as a parameter so you can change the image source or whatever it is you would like to change.

HTML:

```
<img onclick="changeIt(this)" src='em3.gif' name='example' border='0' />
```

Javascript (make sure it's in the  area):

```
function changeIt(img)
{
    var name = img.src;
    alert(name);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CwvL/).

Comment: Ditto. Thanks for taking the trouble to make a demo fiddle/

Answer (score 1):

have you got any img tag in your html with id "myimage"?
you must make sure that there is an img element with id "myimage" before referencing it!

Answer (score 0):

That's because none of your images have an ID:

```
<img id="myImage" onclick="changeIt()" src='em1.gif' name='example' border='0' />
```

Comment: @user1253847 just use mgraphs answer - its what you really want